# How do I JOIN two tables and then use a CASE expression to determine how they are ORDER BY? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, case

Consider the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
  student_id int,
  student_name varchar(255),
  gender varchar(255),
  dept_id int
);

CREATE TABLE Departments (
  dept_id int,
  dept_name varchar(255),
);
```

My goal is to build a table that shows the number of students enrolled in each subject - ordered by descending number of students....

So far I have this query that does just that:

```
SELECT
    dept_name, count(*) as 'number_of_students'
FROM
    Students
JOIN
    Departments on students.dept_id=Departments.dept_id
GROUP BY
    dept_name
ORDER BY 
    dept_name
```

and get the following results:

```
dept_name       number_of_students
---------       ----------   
History         1
English         2
Math            2
Science         3
```

this is what I want.... however, I need to include a case that will change the ordering depending on if 2 or more departments have the SAME number of students...

If 2 or more departments have the same number of students then the resulting table needs to be sorted ALPHABETICALLY instead so it should look like this:

```
dept_name       number_of_students
---------       ----------   
English         2
History         1
Math            2
Science         3
```

My SQL knowledge kind of ends here.. I have a general idea of how I should do this..using CASE statement maybe? But not sure how or where to put it and how I can compare two subsequent values from the number_of_students column and then make a decision based on that?

Any help or advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky.  You can use window function to see how many departments have the same count and *then* sort based on whether that is every greater than 1:

```
SELECT dept_name, number_of_students
FROM (SELECT d.dept_name, COUNT(*) as number_of_students,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COUNT(*)) as cnt_cnt
      FROM Students s JOIN
           Departments d
           ON s.dept_id = d.dept_id
      GROUP BY d.dept_name
     ) d
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN MAX(cnt_cnt) OVER () > 1 THEN dept_name END),
         number_of_student;
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea.. im trying this one and keep getting syntax error regarding '('

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    dept_name, count(*) as 'number_of_students'
FROM
    Student
JOIN
    Departments on student.dept_id=Departments.dept_id
GROUP BY
    dept_name
ORDER BY 
     (CASE WHEN number_of_students = number_of_students THEN dept_name ELSE number_of_students
     END)
```

I solved it